# How to pass arguments to seeder from controller method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to create a dynamic model.

In fact, I have this seeder :

```
class TestSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('tests')->insert([
            'name_test' => $name_test
        ]);
    }
}
```

And I need to send arguments from my controller :

```
public function addTest(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
            'name_test' => 'required|max:255'
        ], [
            'name_test.required' => 'Es necesario rellenar el campo de nombre',
            'name_test.max' => 'El nombre del test debe ser máxim de 255 catacteres',
        ]);

    $input = $request->all();

    //$test = Test::create($input);

    return back()->with('success', 'El test se ha creado correctamente.');
}
```

However, I have no idea how I can do it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you actually trying to create a model instance or you want to run the seeder? Because from what you described it seems like you actually just want to create a model instance

Comment: @EdwardChew I want to run the seeder but whit arguments gived by inputs on a form

Comment: That does not make sense if you just want to insert a row to your DB. `Test::create()` will be the proper way. Do you have any other concern actually?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the TestSeeder class directly:

```php
$test = new TestSeeder;
$test->run($request->name_test);
```

```php
public function run($name_test)
{
    DB::table('tests')->insert([
        'name_test' => $name_test
    ]);
}
```

However, the seeder classes in Laravel are meant for initial data set up, when running tests or when you want to regularly refresh the database in your local environment, for example. You're better off to just run the insert right in the controller - nothing wrong with that when you're testing!

Answer (score 0):

**in controller:**

```
$data = new \Database\Seeders\DomainDemoDataSeeder();
$data->run($request->domain_id, $request->id);
```

**in seeder:**

```
 public function run($domainId, $userId) {
    $uiPages = [
        [
            'name' => 'header',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'footer'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'home',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'about',
        ]
    ];
    foreach ($uiPages as $uiPage) {
        UiPages::create([
            'name' => $uiPage['name'],
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'domain_id' => $domainId
        ]);
    }
 }
```